# How to split string of HTML into pieces and strip outer tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preferably with jQuery for consistency with context, but pure JS is obviously fine.

Given a string like this, `<li><img src="something.jpg"></li><li><img src="something2.jpg"></li>`, how can I convert it to this:

`['<img src="something.jpg">', '<img src="something2.jpg">']`

So I want to strip the `li` tags away and get an array of the images. I know I can `split` the `li`s to get the array, but how can I easily strip the `li` tags off without doing it by hand?

Comment: wait do you need it all in strings or want to end up with an array of jquery image elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this Fiddle for a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sMQdw/

```
// Assuming "string" is your string, this will create an UL in memory and
// adding the string will build a DOM structure out of it
var $temp = $("<ul />").html(string);
var images = [];
// We then use jQuery to extract the LI elements from the DOM structure and
// then append the .html() result from each to the array to get the image strings.
$temp.find("li").each(function() {
  images.push($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = [];
var str = '<li><img src="something.jpg"></li><li><img src="something2.jpg"></li>';

$(str).find('img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    result.push($this.html());    
});
```

This should work then.

Comment: `final` (ecma2+3) and `finally` are reserved words in JavaScript. Might want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using replace, it could possibly be more optimised

```
var str = '<li><img src="something.jpg"></li><li><img src="something2.jpg"></li>';

str = str.replace(/<\/?li>/g,'');
str = str.replace('><','>,<');
str = str.split(',');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qaQ9/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is simply:

```
var string = '<li><img src="something.jpg"></li><li><img src="something2.jpg" /></li>',
    temp = $(string),
    contents = temp.contents().map(function(){
        return this.outerHTML;
    }).get();
console.log(contents);
// ["<img src="something.jpg">", "<img src="something2.jpg">"] 
// this is the literal console.log() output, despite looking like a
// JavaScript string/syntax error.
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NcTm7/).

If you want an array of `img` elements (in this case) you could instead `return this`:

```
var string = '<li><img src="something.jpg"></li><li><img src="something2.jpg" /></li>',
    temp = $(string),
    contents = temp.contents().map(function(){
        return this;
    }).get();
console.log(contents);
// ["<img src="something.jpg">", "<img src="something2.jpg">"] 
// this is the literal console.log() output, despite looking like a
// JavaScript string/syntax error.
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NcTm7/1/).

References:

- [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).